# Prove this function is periodic.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, periodic-functions

The question given in my Real Analysis textbook is as follows:

Let there be f: $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a periodic function with period T and a $\in$ $\mathbb{R^*}$.

Prove the function  $x → f (ax)$ is periodic and determine its period. Lastly, prove that the period is the answer previously obtained.

My take on this would be as follows:

By the definition given by my textbook, a function is periodic if $f(x)=f(x+T)$ and we already know that f is periodic.

Lets note $ f(ax) = f_a(x)$

Let's firstly consider $a>0$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have:
$f_a(x + (T/a)) = f(ax+T)= f(ax)=f_a(x)$

Then we consider the same thing for $a<0$

$f_a(x+(T/|a|)) = f(ax-T)= f(ax-T+T)=f(ax)=f_a(x)$

So for all $a\neq 0$, $f_a(x+(T/|a|)) = f_a(x)$

// which shows that the function is indeed periodic so we have proved the first part of the question.
I hope this proof is correct :')

So the period is $T/|a|$

**Now we have to prove that the period is indeed $T/|a|$**

I have some ideas for this but in not sure how to properly express them mathematically.
So by definition we know that the period of a periodic function has to be the smallest $T>0$.

So maybe here we can prove by contrapositive? so assume that there is another period $T^\prime$ which is greater than zero but smaller than $T/|a|$ such that $f_a(x+T^\prime)=f_a(x)$
Now we need to show why this would be impossible but I'm not quite sure how to continue.
**So how would I finish this proof?**

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: As was the case with your prior question, the point here is that the "period" has to be the least *positive* number such that $f(x+p)=f(x)$.  As $\frac Ta$ need not be positive,  it may not be the period.

Comment: @lulu oh can't believe I didn't consider that! Tysm! Any idea on how I could finish the proof for the period being T/|a|?

Comment: As you suggest, argue by contradiction.  Suppose the translated function has some period (not necessarily minimal) with $0<\tau<\frac T{|a|}$.  Deduce that the original function must have had a period less than $T$, a contradiction.